# Issue on Applying Style Only For Popover Assigned to Specific Div in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to apply style to Bootstrap 3 Popover at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/sbrnwqrp/)

The following ruke apply new style to all Popover

```
.popover {
    color: red;
}
```

but Need to apply this to ONLY popovers which are associated  `#pop` div. I already tried

```
#pop .popover {
    color: red;
}
```

or

```
#pop> .popover {
    color: red;
}
```

but they didn't do the job either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can style the popover content with... popover-content class :

```
.popover-content {
    color: red;
}
```